# How to update sdk in android

Tags: android, eclipse

HI I am doing project in andoroid using eclipse, and I am completly new to this stuffs just a day before I updated my AVD manger through this link http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ but now I am not able to open my SDK. It's giving an error message like this `[2015-03-01 00:25:38 - DDMS] DDMS files not found: C:\android\sdk\platform-tools\hprof-conv.exe`

So can anyone please tell me how to get ride of this error and get my SDK anger running?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to update your SDK as well. Use the "SDK Manager" it's right next to the AVD Manager in the menu.

Comment: thank you. i manged to update my sdk i restarted it and its working fine now thank you so much